# How to simulate keyboard press on turbo debugger for DOSBOX?

Tags: debugging, assembly, tasm, dosbox

A program I'm writing needs to check keyboard press and loop until it has in the buffer, then check what key was pressed, so when I run it in the debugger, it loops forever because there is no keyboard press.
Until now I've just changed the lines on the program to skip checking keyboard and jump right to the place I want to check, but is there any less exhausting way to do it?

Comment: My debugger has a serial I/O mode in which you can control the debugger from a different terminal than the one used by the client. That requires setting up a serial port on the DOS side then connecting that to a different terminal. Plug: https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug

Comment: More generally you may be able to get your/any debugger to set a temporary or permanent breakpoint on an instruction that will run after the application has finished reading input, then instruct the debugger to "run" or "go" to the next breakpoint. That should allow you to enter something to the application and then have it return control to the debugger's interface afterwards.

Comment: Can you use the debugger built-in to DOSBox, or run in Bochs and use its built-in debugger?  Those put the debugger outside the guest system, so the guest doesn't "know" its being debugged, and there's no competition between debugger and target for the system keyboard.  (@ecm's serial-port idea would be handy if you needed to do this on real hardware, or if it's hard to get the full-system debugger to stop in your DOS program's code).  If you were writing programs for a modern multi-tasking OS, the program could have a terminal to itself, again with non-intrusive debugging.